# Finding the occurrence of / in url

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of html links as such:

```
https://locations.foo.com/united-states/me/auburn/address-address
```

I am interested in extracting the 'me' part of the string. But I want to iterate this over a bunch of urls.
I know I have to look at the strings `/` character. It is consistent throughout all urls that I would need to extract between the fourth(4th) and fifth(5th) `/`. Do I need a regex expression of some sort to extract this as an object? Or is it even simpler?

Comment: Qs: how will you know what `me` stands for? How will you be able to tell if you got `me` and not `auburn`? Are all urls from the same domain, with the same structure?

Answer (score 2):

Wont a simple split and grab by index suffice?

```js
url = 'https://locations.foo.com/united-states/me/auburn/address-address'
wanted_part = url.split('/')[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

More specific to `me`:

```
url = 'https://locations.foo.com/united-states/me/auburn/address-address'

console.log(url.split('/')[4].split('/')[0])
```

gets string between 4th and 5th

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is always in the same format, then you should go with a simpler approach like what others suggested (i.e `split` for example).

But, if your URL format changes with differing patterns, then, as the number of patterns increases, a regular expression solution will be a better or maybe only solution.

For example: all of the following URLs are valid in a browser and the `split` solution can't handle the variation easily.

https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/63405024/finding-the-occurrence-of-in-url https:stackoverflow.com/questions/63405024/finding-the-occurrence-of-in-url stackoverflow.com/questions/63405024/finding-the-occurrence-of-in-url